# Passing the same chain of parameters multiple times with currying

Tags: functional-programming, f#, currying

Given this expression:

```
// val fn1 : a:'a -> b:'b -> c:'c -> d:'d -> e:'e -> f:'f -> g:'g -> unit
// val fn2 : a:'a -> b:'b -> c:'c -> d:'d -> e:'e -> f:'f -> g:'g -> unit

type T =
  | A
  | B

// val t : T
// val a : 'a
// val b : 'b
// val c : 'c
// val d : 'd
// val e : 'e
// val f : 'f
// val g : 'g

match t with
| A -> fn1 a b c d e f g
| B -> fn2 a b c d e f g
```

Is there a way to not repeat the same chain of parameters while calling a function that supports currying? so you could write some weird stuff like this

```
(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
|||||||> (match t with A -> fn1 | B -> fn2)
```

Would this be a case for an anonymous record? What are the common practices to achieve this?

Comment: If your function has 10 parameters, you probably missed some

Comment: @FyodorSoikin ohhh that was confusing, sorry! I added some signatures.

Comment: For readability, I would do `let f = match... `, then once `f a b c d e`. Or parens around it and apply (as the first answer shows). If you have the same set of parameters on multiple functions, create a record, a type alias or single case DU for clearer code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply, rather than pipes?

```
(match t with
| A -> curried1
| B -> curried2
) 1 2 3 4
```

FSharp closures are implemented as `FSharpFunc<T, TResult>`, which have an invoke method which let you call the method without multiple partial applications.

I wouldn't recommend going that way, but in extreme cases you can use reflection to invoke a function with an array of parameters.

```
let funInvoke fn args =
        let fnType = fn.GetType()
        if not (FSharpType.IsFunction fnType) then
            failwith "Not a function"

        let invoke = Array.head (fnType.GetMethods())
        invoke.Invoke(fn, args)
```

and then

```
funInvoke curried1 [|1; 2; 3 ; 4 |]
```

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions by @Asti work fine. I would go one step further in simplifying the first one. I prefer to name things, so that I can remember what they mean, so I would write:

```
let funcToCall = match t with | A -> curried1 | B -> curried2
funcToCall 1 2 3 4
```

However, I think there is a valid point in the comments that you have too many parameters. In this case, it makes much more sense to use a named record:

```
type FuncParams = { Doors:int; Windows:int; Walls:int; Chimneys:int; .... }

let arg = { Doors=1; Windows=2; Walls=3; Chimneys=4; ... }
match t with A -> curried1 arg | B -> curried2 arg
```

Comment: Thats it! Naming then applying worked for now. Eventually I will create a record, but now I'm in a smelly part trying to figure out how to deal with all this parameter passing. Thanks guys